# How can select a row from other table as json result for current field of selection

Tags: mysql, sql

Assume I have

```
A:
Id  Name
1    a
2    b

B:
Id  AId Date
1    2   123
```

I want to build a query something like this:

```
SELECT B.*,(SELECT * FROM A WHERE Id=B.AId) AS AJsonObject FROM B

Result:

Id AId Date     AJsonObject
1   2   123       {"Id":2, "Name":"b"}
```

How can I perform this?

Comment: Why you donot use backend script to format rows into json?

Comment: I want to use mysql query to make faster my api.

Comment: Ok. Please go through this [link](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/json.html)

MySQL 5.7.8, MySQL supports a native JSON data type. This constraint must be adhered.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT B.*,(SELECT * FROM A  inner join B on A.Id=B.AId) AS AJsonObject FROM B;
```

Comment: Although this code may help to solve the problem, it doesn't explain _why_ and/or _how_ it answers the question. Providing this additional context  would significantly improve its long-term educational value. Please [edit] your answer to add explanation, including what limitations and assumptions apply.